# Symfony query ids from ManyToMany relation table for every entity item

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have two entities Article and Tag with a Many to Many relation. For a bulk edit I query some attributes from every Articles. In that query I also want to query all assigned Tag-IDs from every Article.

I read something about the function GROUP_CONCAT() but Doctrine doesn't support that function yet.

My Doctrine statement is currently like that:

```
$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT e.articleId, e.articleTitle, t.tagId FROM App\Entity\Article e LEFT JOIN e.tags t');
```

It would be best to fetch those assigned Tag-IDs as an array.

Comment: Does your current work ? What is the current result vs the expected one ?

Comment: The current statement returns for every Tag ID from relation table ONE Article row with ONE Tag ID

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions because it includes group_concat for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

So I extended Doctrine with GROUP_CONCAT function from [github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) and use following code to get all IDs as an array:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('SELECT e.articleId, e.articleTitle, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tagId) AS tagIds FROM App\Entity\Article e LEFT JOIN e.tags t GROUP BY e.articleId');
        $articleArray = $query->execute();

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($articleArray); $i++) {
            if (strpos($articleArray[$i]['tagIds'], ',')) {
                $arr = array_map('intval', explode(',', $articleArray[$i]['tagIds']));
                $articleArray[$i]['tagIds'] = ($arr) ? $arr : [];
            }
            elseif (!is_null($articleArray[$i]['tagIds'])) $articleArray[$i]['tagIds'] = [(int) $articleArray[$i]['tagIds']];
            else continue;
        }
```